# Scroll to a div when click on a button with smooth behavior

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a new behavior when the user click on the `button .employers-button` I am going to scroll down to the `form #contact`in JS.

I implemented a function with `window.scrool` and the current top is `top: 200` (as it as to be a value).

It is working but how can I replace the `top: 2000` by `top: contact`? I tried to put `contact` instead of `2000` but it is not going down at all since it was to be an `int`

```
const goToContact = () => {
    const button = document.getElementsByClassName("employers-button")[0];
    const contact = document.getElementById("contact");
    button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        window.scroll({
            top: 2000,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) with `behavior:smooth` to scroll to specific element and to avoid any hacks.

codepen:https://codepen.io/murliprajapati/pen/RwwLYyR

```js
function scrollToElement() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth', block:'start'});
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin-top:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV">
  <button onclick="scrollToElement()">Scroll</button>
  <div id="content">
    Some text inside an element.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchor tags

```css
.big-space{
height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#myForm">Button that scroll</a>
<div class="big-space">
</div>
<form id="myForm">
<label>form here</label>
<input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but the behavior is not smooth

Comment: @Tom1999 please state in your question what your expected requirements are, no where did you state that the scroll should be smooth.

Answer (score 1):

For the smooth transition, I made the following fiddle. The property you were looking for is [offsetTop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsettop.asp). Hope this help!

```js
const button = document.getElementById("employers-button");
const contact = document.getElementById("contact");
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    window.scroll({
        top: contact.offsetTop,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 3000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
#contact {
  margin-top: 1800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="employers-button">Let's scroll!</button>
<div id="contact">Contact</div>
```

Comment: Im guessing that the 2000 should be a variable of the position of the contact form

Comment: Working perfectly (can't accept the answer since I am a new user)

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to the community! If I am correct, you can accept an answer (the greyed out checkmark next to an answer),  but not yet upvote it until you have 15 rep. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```js
VANILLA
top: contact.offsetTop;

Or JQUERY
top: contact.offset().top;
// but if you want it positioned relative to the closest positioned parent:
top: contact.position().top
```

Contact, in this case, is a DOM element, and as you rightly mentioned the top property of `window.scroll` expects a number.

Comment: "main.js:64 Uncaught TypeError: contact.position is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:64)"

Comment: AM sorry @Tom1999, I thought you were using jQuery. You can use contact.offsetTop. I will update my answer